# Workbook_Open() method causes crash

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with VBA spread over several modules, class modules, and user form modules. The workbook is saved as a macro-enabled Excel workbook (*.xlsm), and it runs just fine when starting the `Main` method from the Alt+F8 macro dialog window. The code also runs fine when "stepping" through it in the Alt+F11 developer window—although, this method takes a *very* long time, as the total code is thousands of lines long with many loops.

The problem arises when I add the following code to the `ThisWorkbook` module. When I insert this code, Excel crashes immediately upon open.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Main
End Sub
```

The `Main` method called here refers to a subprocedure in the module `MainModule`. It has no parameters, required or optional, and all necessary variables are properly declared in the `MainModule` module under an `Option Explicit` statement.

I need the macro to run on load, because I plan to set up a scheduled Windows task to run it at a regular interval through a VBS file. What's going on? Why does calling the `Main()` method from the `Workbook_Open()` method cause Excel to crash, while running the `Main()` method manually works OK?

**Edit:** Code of `Main()` method.

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim allTickets As Collection
    Dim grpTickets As Collection
    Dim sa() As String
    Dim strConfig() As String
    Dim rptFp As String
    Dim i As Integer

    SetDefaults

    If DEV_ENABLED Then
        Application.WindowState = xlNormal
        If MsgBox( _
            Prompt:="Run reporting script?", _
            Buttons:=vbYesNo _
        ) = vbNo Then Terminate
        Application.WindowState = xlMinimized
    End If

    MainForm.Show vbModeless
    EnsureCfgPath
    LoadConfig

    ' Check for valid config in memory.
    On Error Resume Next
    If Len(config(0)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Could not validate or create config file. Please contact support for assistance."
        Terminate
    ElseIf Err.Number <> 0 Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        MsgBox "Could not validate or create config file. Please contact support for assistance."
        Terminate
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Import tickets from BA files.
    Set allTickets = ImportBAData(config(1))

    ' Create report(s) identified by config file.
    ReDim strConfig(7)
    For i = 0 To Ubound(config) Step 8
        On Error Resume Next
        strConfig(0) = config(i)
        strConfig(1) = config(i + 1)
        strConfig(2) = config(i + 2)
        strConfig(3) = config(i + 3)
        strConfig(4) = config(i + 4)
        strConfig(5) = config(i + 5)
        strConfig(6) = config(i + 6)
        strConfig(7) = config(i + 7)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Logger "[MainModule:Main] Config file contains too few options. Adopting ""END"" command option."
            strConfig(7) = "!~END//~!"
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        sa = Split(strConfig(5), ",")
        Set grpTickets = FilterTickets(allTickets, strConfig(4), sa)
        ' Create report.
        rptFp = CreateReport(configs:=strConfig, Tickets:=grpTickets)
        ' Send report.
        If Not rptFp = ".xlsx" Then SendReport FilePath:=rptFp, Recipients:=strConfig(6)
        If strConfig(7) = "!~END//~!" Then
            Exit For
        ElseIf Not strConfig(7) = "!~FOLLOW//~!" Then
            Logger "[MainModule:Main] Illegal config option """ & strConfig(7) & """ passed. Terminating process."
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    MainForm.SetStatus("Cleaning up...")
    Terminate
End Sub
```

**Edit2:** Very, *very* odd resolution.

Excel was still crashing immediately, no matter where I placed an `Exit Sub` statement in `Main`. So, I commented out everything in `Main`, except the `Exit Sub` statement, and then saved and closed. Next, I opened the workbook, and it didn't crash—it executed the `Exit Sub` statement just fine. So, I removed the `Exit Sub` statement, and uncommented the code in `Main`, and now it works.

I'm chalking this one up to poor QA on Microsoft's part.

Comment: Post the code for `Main()`. Probably going to be difficult to diagnose without it.

Comment: Suggest cutting out bits of Main to find out what is causing the issue. Can you add a dummy procedure with MsgBox "Hello World!"? Have you tried on another version of Excel or even another OS? Bear in mind that usually macros are disabled by default, so you might be best off having a "Run Me" button on the toolbar for the macro instead of trying to run on load.

Comment: I doubt the `Main()` method is the problem, since it runs just fine when started manually. It's only when I add code to the `Workbook_Open()` method that Excel crashes. Editing question with redacted `Main()` method code.

Comment: @AlainD The `Main()` method needs to be started automatically when the workbook loads, because the workbook will be opened on a schedule in Windows Task Scheduler. The macro needs to run without user intervention. Excel is configured to allow the worksheet's location to run all macros.

Comment: OK, understood. Try cutting out bits of Main till it works. Put "Exit Sub" further and further down till...bingo! it works. You don't say what version of Excel you're using, BTW.

Comment: Using Excel 2013 on Windows 7 Enterprise, 64-bit. Forgot to mention that. Sorry! ^_^;

Answer (score 0):

When I set up the following code to test, I get no errors.

In module1:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Main()
  MsgBox "Hello World"
End Function
```

In the Workbooks_Open:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Main
End Sub
```

Test this and if it is not working in a saved XLSM file then the problem may be how Excel is configured. (e.g. check trusted settings, allow VBA...)

Comment: But the trusted settings or disallowed VBA shouldn't cause Excel to _crash_ (i.e., fatally error).

Comment: @T6J2E5: Complex products do crash. Its part of life. I have Office 2000 running fine on Windows XP but rather unstable on Windows 8. Since you don't have control over Excel or VBA or the OS...you just need to be practical. Excel is crashing. Work round it.